# Create list from checkbox loop

Tags: jquery, loops, checkbox

I have the following code where I would like the values of each of the checkboxes to be added to a list.
I'm not sure of the correct syntax for this, any help would be appreciated.
This what I am thinking of:

```
var = lstCheckedDefects;

$("#defectsModal .defect_selection:checked").each(function(){
 lstCheckedDefects = lstCheckedDefects + ($(this).attr("value"))
});
```

ok how do I use the solution in an ajax post I have this code but not able to send the lstCheckedDefects as a list:

```
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:"index.cfm?action=claim.update_claim_qa_defect",
                cache: false,
                data:{
                    claim_id: claim_id,
                    row_id: row_id,
                    code_def: code_def,
                    defect_selection: lstCheckedDefects
                },
                success:function(result){

                }});
```

Many thanks

JC

Comment: and what is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something more like this:

```
var lstCheckedDefects = [];

$("#defectsModal .defect_selection:checked").each(function( index, element ){
    lstCheckedDefects.push($(element).val());
});
```